# Template matching for rotated images using a fast Fourier transform

Tags: fft, template-matching

I want to find a rotated fragment taken from a large image using a fast Fourier transform.

I know how to do this in case the image is not rotated. To do this, it is enough to calculate the similarity function of two images in the frequency domain and find the extremum.

How to solve the problem in the case of a rotated image?

Comment: please review [ask]. research is your responsibility. can you tell if this is mathematically even possible, with nothing but a fourier transform? at some point you'd need another transform to become rotation-invariant.

Comment: Arbitrary rotation or multiples of 90 degrees ?

Comment: @PaulR Arbitrary rotation